# Math.log() inaccuracy - How to deal with it?

Tags: javascript, math

I know that for getting a 10 based logarithm I have to use Math.log() divided by the constant of the natural logarithm of 10.

```
var e1000 = Math.log(1000) / Math.LN10;

// Result: 2.9999999999999996 instead of 
//   expected 3.
console.log(e1000); 

// Result:  999.999999999999 instead of
//   expected 1000.
console.log(Math.pow(10, e1000));
```

BUT: The result is just an approximation. If I use the calculated value in further calculation the inaccuracy becomes worse.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there are more elegant way around it then just using Math.ceil()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3439981/251311

Comment: In general, you can't expect floating point numbers to be exact.  If your program relies on that, you'll need to rethink your approach.

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicate with current questions mentioned, first I think the main theme of is question is about log,but not floating point issue. Also, even solving floating point is a solution, it may be one of solutions only , there may be some solutions specific to log (e.g.: division until 0) other than solving float point issue.

Comment: @amuse, I agree with you, this question is about solving the specific effect the floating point issue has on log10 and finding a workable solution/alternative for log10, not about the occurrence of floating calculation differences in general. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating point rounding difference is known and coincidentally the 2.9999 is the exact example used in the [MDN Math.Log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log) page.
As you mentioned `Math.ceiling` can be used to alther the result. Likewise you could increase the base number and use a smaller divider to decrease the change of floating errors. e.g.

```
function log10(value){
  return -3 * (Math.log(value * 100)  / Math.log(0.001))  - 2;
}
```

Example: [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/vicazasugo/1/edit?js,console)

As a sidenote, some browsers already support the Math.[log10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10) functionality, you could extend `Math` to use the function above if it is not implemented with:

```
if (!Math.log10) Math.log10 = function(value){
  return -3 * (Math.log(value * 100)  / Math.log(0.001))  - 2;
};
```

After running that initializer, you can simply use `Math.log10()` and your code will automatically use the browser functionality where it is (or when it becomes) available. ([fiddle](http://jsbin.com/vizozifofe/edit?js,console))

Comment: "e1000 = (Math.log(1000 * 100000) / Math.LN10) - 5;" works perfectly fine. :-) Thanks a lot. You're awesome.

Comment: :) Thanks, glad you could use it. Was curious to see if it behaved well with log10s of fractions too and was happy to see it did. Although log10(0.01) still gave a rounding difference which was solved with a slightly larger base: `(Math.log(value * 1000000) / Math.LN10) - 6;`

Comment: hmm, with 6, 1000 gives rounding errors again, perhaps it's not as generic as I hoped it would be

Comment: Mmhh ... I'm afraid you're right. "2.9999999999999982" in Firebug / Firefox.

Comment: Did some fiddling around, by also decreasing the divider it seems to work `-3 * (Math.log(value * 100)  / Math.log(0.001))  - 2;`

Comment: allrighty, that was a fun excercise, tested the function on firefox, chrome and ie, where it produced the expected results for all numbers in the test code `for(var v = 0.001; v <= 10000000; v*=10)
  console.log( log10(v));`

Comment: Yep. Works and produces an interesting output on the console if you write "console.log( v + ': ' + Math.log10(v));" ;-) Thx!

Comment: Have put this Q&A on Twitter It provoked a lot of favs & retweets. Thank you a lot for you're endeavour.

Comment: @Me.Name the `*=` operator in your program already introduces rounding errors. Unless you write the fractions as float literals or a expressions of the form `1.0 / powerOfTen`, the result of your code doesn't prove anything at all.